# Run a background wcf service call in MVC applicaiton

Tags: multithreading, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

In my MVC web application, I use a WCF services.

Once the user sign In, I need to update the "lastLoggedOnDate" for the user as a background WCF service call.

I want the user login process to be completed and not wait for this service call.

How can I do this?

```
Person personObj = null;
using (var services = new ServiceFactory())
{
personObj = services.Person.GetUserByLoginDetails(user.Username,-parameters-);
}

--Authentication process --
--If authentication success --
              --BACKGROUND CALL TO WCF service ??
```

Answer (score 0):

In case the background task spans the boundary of a single HTTP request/response, there are at least two options to deal with this:

- Delegate the pending task to a separate process like Windows Service ([a similar question](http://alandjackson.wordpress.com/2012/04/11/long-running-background-tasks-in-asp-net-mvc3/)).
- Create a static task scheduler (singleton object), which would run the task inside the ASP.NET process space. More details: [Long Running Background Tasks in Asp.Net MVC3](http://alandjackson.wordpress.com/2012/04/11/long-running-background-tasks-in-asp-net-mvc3/).